# python - creating dictionary from excel using specific columns

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, xlrd

I'm relatively new to python (outside of the world of GIS) and struggling getting the code I won't for a side project I am doing with USGS Earthquake data. The data is in an excel file containing 7 columns as seen below:

[USGS earthquake table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPrdC.png)

I have these tasks which I set myself:

1. Total number of earthquakes
2. Create Dictionary of Time of Earthquakes with the Region
3. Top 3 locations with the highest frequency of earthquakes
4. Top 3 locations with the highest magnitude of earthquakes
5. Print the above to text file

I am stuck on second task and once I have that i should be able to do the rest.

Also, I'm aware that nothing gets printed to text file yet!

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
from collections import Counter

def get_sheet(xl_file):
    wb = open_workbook(xl_file,'r')

    # get first sheet in the workbook
    return wb.sheets()[0]

def number_eq(sheet):
    row_count = len(range(sheet.nrows))
    print ("Total number of earthqaukes = %s") % row_count

def no_earthquake_region():

    #???

#def top_freq_eq(sheet):

    #print (Counter(words).most_common(5))

#def top_mag_eq(sheet):

    #print (Counter(words).most_common(5))

def main(xl_file, out_folder):

    sheet = get_sheet(xl_file)
    row = number_eq(sheet)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xl_file = r'D:\Projects\Other\data\EarthquakeUSGS.xlsx'
    out_folder = r"D:\Projects\Other\data\output\output.txt"
    main(xl_file, out_folder)
    print("Done!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I'll do it:

```
    import xlrd
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    from collections import Counter

    def get_sheet(xl_file):
        wb = open_workbook(xl_file,'r')

        # get first sheet in the workbook
        return wb.sheets()[0]

    def number_eq(sheet):
        row_count = len(range(sheet.nrows))
        print ("Total number of earthqaukes = %s") % row_count

    def no_earthquake_region(sheet):
        l = []
        num_of_rows = sheet.nrows
        num_of_cols = sheet.ncols
        if(num_of_rows > 1):
            d={}
            for i in range(2,num_of_rows):
                d = {"Time":sheet.cell(i,1).value , "Region":sheet.cell(i,6).value}
                l.append(d)
        return l

    #def top_freq_eq(sheet):

        #print (Counter(words).most_common(5))

    #def top_mag_eq(sheet):

        #print (Counter(words).most_common(5))

    def main(xl_file, out_folder):

        sheet = get_sheet(xl_file)
        row = number_eq(sheet)
        print no_earthquake_region(sheet)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        xl_file = r'D:\Projects\Other\data\EarthquakeUSGS.xlsx'
        out_folder = r"D:\Projects\Other\data\output\output.txt"
        main(xl_file, out_folder)
        print("Done!")
```